# Crash at tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm getting this crash more and more since iOS 13 released, to get to the point i register the cells this

```
self.messagesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MessagesCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesCell")
self.messagesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "NativeAdCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

And the way to use them in `cellForrow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if pageArray.count == 0 {return UITableViewCell()}
        if pageArray.isValidIndex(indexPath.row) == false {return UITableViewCell()}

        if pageArray[indexPath.row] is UIView{

            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? NativeAdCell {

                return cell

            }else {

                return UITableViewCell()

            }

        }else {

            if let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessagesCell", for: indexPath) as? MessagesCell {

                return cell

            }else {

                return UITableViewCell()
            }

        }

}
```

Here is the log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  APPNAME                        0x1002a4f68 MessagesDetail.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4341010280 (<compiler-generated>:4341010280)
1  APPNAME                        0x1002a4ffc @objc MessagesDetail.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4341010428 (<compiler-generated>:4341010428)
2  UIKitCore                      0x1c6285880 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 640
3  UIKitCore                      0x1c6252f40 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2608
4  UIKitCore                      0x1c6270108 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 160
5  UIKitCore                      0x1c653617c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140
6  QuartzCore                     0x1c8a9e2c0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
7  QuartzCore                     0x1c8aa443c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480
8  QuartzCore                     0x1c8aaf140 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136
9  QuartzCore                     0x1c89f7884 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 304
10 QuartzCore                     0x1c8a21574 CA::Transaction::commit() + 676
11 QuartzCore                     0x1c8a21f68 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1c1f97e68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1c1f92d54 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1c1f93320 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1c1f92adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
16 GraphicsServices               0x1cbf33328 GSEventRunModal + 104
17 UIKitCore                      0x1c60a063c UIApplicationMain + 1936
18 APPNAME                        0x10025c68c main + 21 (SearchViewController.swift:21)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x1c1e1c360 start + 4
```

Now i am completely lost, i'm not receiving this crash with all users just specific ones, why ? and could someone explain what i'm exactly doing wrong ?

i tried different kind of error logging or main thread checker or all exceptions but nothing came up.

Comment: please add crash log

Comment: @Sh_Khan done my mistake.

Comment: @matt it’s line number 0 , I missed my code up just to figure out what’s wrong and I couldn’t.

Answer (score -1):

There are some of horrible things here to point to

1-  If array is empty then `cellForRowAt` won't be called so this is useless

```
if pageArray.count == 0 {return UITableViewCell()}
```

2- You need to filter your data before reloading the table so this is useless

```
if pageArray.isValidIndex(indexPath.row) == false {return UITableViewCell()}
```

3- Don't use `if let` here

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? NativeAdCell {
```

as if the table registers the cell , then it will 100% return a cell , instead use

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NativeAdCell
```

4- You don't have to put views inside the array you need a bool logic instead

```
if pageArray[indexPath.row] is UIView{
```

Comment: What’s the part that explains the crash?